# Каким членом предложения является слово "для"?

Tags: синтаксис

Каким членом предложения является слово "для"?

Answer (score 3):

Слово "для" — предлог.  Предлоги никогда не выступают в качестве членов предложения.

> Предло́г — служебная часть речи, обозначающая отношение между объектом и субъектом, выражающая синтаксическую зависимость имен существительных, местоимений, числительных от других слов в словосочетаниях и предложениях. Предлоги, как и все служебные слова, не могут употребляться самостоятельно, они всегда относятся к какому-нибудь существительному (или слову, употребляемому в функции существительного). Вследствие своей синтаксической несамостоятельности предлоги никогда не выступают в качестве членов предложения. Они обслуживают управление как вид подчинительной связи, будучи связанными с управляющим компонентом словосочетания. ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3))

Comment: В некоторых особых случаях предлог может быть подлежащим: *"Для" является простым предлогом* :)

Comment: @Сибиряк В данном случае слово "для" является не предлогом, а просто словом. Действительно, особый случай.

Comment: А вопрос и есть про слово.

Comment: Это своего рода логическая подмена. Пишем ["для"] вместо [слово "для"] и написанное начинает играть в предложении ту синтаксическую роль, которую должно играть слово "слово". Такой фокус можно проделать с любым словом. Просто нужно различать сам предлог и его название, хоть и пишутся они одинаково.

Comment: Это не всегда предлог :)

Answer (score 3):

Помимо уже упоминавшегося *подлежащего*, это слово может быть *дополнением*:

> Из всех бесчисленных предлогов он выбрал почему-то "для". Этим "для" и
>   ограничился.

а в форме деепричастия образует с другими словами оборот, являющийся *обстоятельством* образа действия:

> Пел песню странник, **для** свой путь.

Comment: Вопрос в том, что понимать под словом. По мне так в "для свой путь" у нас словоформа слова "длить"

Comment: А взятое в кавычки имя (название) любого слова может играть все синтаксические роли, которые играют имена.

Comment: Вопрос поставлен без ограничений :)

Comment: Да это ловушка! :). Надо вопрос конкретизировать.